# Subsetting Identical Observations in R

Tags: r, vector, logic, subset

I am trying to look at protein sequence homology using R, and I'd like to go through a data frame looking for identical pairs of Position and Letter. The data look similar to the frame below:

```
Letter <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E", "G", "L")
Position <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7)
data.set <- cbind(Position, Letter)
```

Which yields:

```
     Position Letter
[1,] "1"      "A"   
[2,] "2"      "B"   
[3,] "3"      "C"   
[4,] "4"      "D"   
[5,] "4"      "D"   
[6,] "5"      "E"   
[7,] "6"      "G"   
[8,] "7"      "L"
```

I'd like to loop through and find all identical observations (in this case, observations 4 and 5), but I'm having difficulty in discovering the best way to do it.

I'd like the resultant data frame to look like:

```
     Position Letter
[1,] "4"      "D"   
[2,] "4"      "D"
```

The ways I've tried to do this ended up yielding this code, but unfortunately it returns one value of TRUE because I realized that I am comparing two identical data frames:

```
> identical(data.set[1:nrow(data.set),1:2], data.set[1:nrow(data.set),1:2])
[1] TRUE
```

I'm not sure if looping through using the identical() function would be the best way? I'm sure there's a more elegant solution that I am missing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` using `fromLast` to go in two directions:

```
data.set[(duplicated(data.set)==T | duplicated(data.set, fromLast = TRUE) == T),]

#     Position Letter
#[1,] "4"      "D"   
#[2,] "4"      "D"
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very valuable for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `unique` function:

```
unique(data.set)
```

...

Comment: Oh my goodness, this is a bit of a facepalm moment... Thank you!